# Problem while writing the cron job using whenever ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, cron, whenever

I am trying to setup a cron job using the [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem. I have written when the cron job should be run in the schedule.rb and also updated the crontab as mentioned in the [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby) episode. But the cron job does not seem to be running.  I am just using it in the local machine.

This is the schedule.rb code

```
every :sunday, :at => "2:28am" do
  runner "App.send_status", :environment => :development
end
```

and this is what comes when I did crontab -l

```
    28 2 * * 0 /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /Users/felix/cron && script/rails runner -e development 
'\''App.send_status'\'''
```

I setup the cron just 5 mins ahead(i.e at 2:23).

It gets executed, when I tried it from the command line like

```
script/rails runner -e development "App.send_status"
```

Could you please tell me whether I am missing something.
Thanks!!!

Comment: you are correct. but is there a way to correct it. it is generated by whenever gem itself

Answer (score 0):

To debug this I would first put some puts with status text in App.send_status

Then go to server and add the following line in 'crontab -e'

```
MAILTO=your@email.com
```

All the puts output should be in your mailbox shortly after execution.

Comment: In case you don't have an MTA installed on the server, the other way to debug it is to add this to your schedule.rb file:  set :output, "#{path}/log/cron_log.txt"
This will then route to the output of the cron job to file in your log directory where you can look at what's wrong.